# Не подключается Javascript

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Здравствуйте не подключается JS. Пути все верные. Даже когда скачиваю например готовый сайт, то там JS не работает, что делать?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="codemirror.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/codemirror.css">

  </head>
  <body>
  <script>

var editor = CodeMirror(document.getElementById("code"));
</script>
    <textarea id="code" name="code">
</textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Вот консоль

Comment: простите что отвечаю вопросом на вопрос но что за codemirror у вас подключень?

Comment: script надо подключить внизу страницы поверх закрываюшего тега body

Comment: Что в консоли браузера на этот счет есть? Есть HTTP-запрос на этот файл? Какой код ответа?

Comment: Подозреваю, что скрипты требуют jQuery.

Comment: вы сначала вызвали скрипт, а потом создали элемент `code`, вот оно и не работает

Comment: Любопытно посмотреть, что в самом скрипте...., может просто сам код в файле не рабочий...

Comment: тут качал попробуйте сами http://codemirror.net/

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
<textarea id="code" name="code"></textarea>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/codemirror.css">

</head>

<body>

<script src="codemirror.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  
</body>

</html>
сделал так тоже не работает

Comment: возможно у кого то другого будет работатать

Comment: Что за "кон" у вас в адресной строке вместо адреса?

Comment: это к теме? оно поможет решить ошибку?

Comment: Если посмотреть в консоль то это поможет решить ошибку

Comment: консоль перед вами вверху

Comment: Откройте вкладку Network и перезагрузите страницу

Answer (score 0):

Подразумеваю, что вы хотели организовать что-то типа этого

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="codemirror.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/codemirror.css">
</head>

<body>

  <textarea id="code" name="code"></textarea>
  <button class="btn">Вывести в консоль</button>

  <script>
    var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var editor = document.getElementById("code").value;
      console.log(editor);
    });
    
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```